# C# - Try/Catch/Finally and Using proper order

Tags: c#, resources, try-catch, dispose, using

I know this question has been asked quite a few times but i still don't understand what the proper order should be.

If you want to catch an exception in the objects creation you have to put the try and catch outside of the using statement:

```
try { using... } catch (Exception e) { }
```

And if you want to catch an exception after the objects creation then:

```
using(...) { try {...} catch (Exception e) {} }
```

But what if you want to catch both during and after the objects creation? Would it be:

```
try { using(...) { try {...} catch (Exception e) {} } } catch (Exception e) { }
```

Or would it be better to just use a try, catch, and a finally with a dispose?

Comment: Option 1 would catch both

Comment: @hardkoded could you explain how?

Comment: Since the object is created inside your using() statement, and the try is outside that block ... the first try will catch it.

Comment: why are you comparing try and using. those 2 are for different purposes and all you need is to have try at the right place

Comment: Why do i see mixed answers everywhere? When would you use a try and catch within a using statement?

Answer (score 6):

The [using block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) is more about the Disposal than the creation. As mentioned in the documentation, it's a shortcut to this code:

```
{
    Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
    try
    {
        byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (font1 != null)
            ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
    }
}
```

This is the definition of a [try-catch block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

> The try block contains the guarded code that may cause the exception.
>   The block is executed until an exception is thrown or it is completed
>   successfully.

So from there, the strategy is up to you. This piece of code:

```
try
{
    using(Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
    {
        byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
    }
}
```

will be translated as:

```
try
{
    Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
    try
    {
        byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (font1 != null)
            ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
   }
}
```

As you can see, you are catching exceptions cause by the constructor, the block and also the `Dispose`.

Whereas this:

```
using(Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
{
    try
    {
        byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
    }
}
```

will be translated as:

```
Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
try
{
    try //This is your try
    {
      byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
    }
}
finally
{
    if (font1 != null)
        ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
}
```

So here you will catch exception cause neither by the constructor nor the Dispose.

Comment: Good catch! Not only the object creation, but also its disposal can throw.

Comment: So the try and catch should always be outside the using statement?

Comment: @shnk If you want to catch the constructor, the block and the dispose, yes

Comment: Including everything inside the using statement as well right?

Comment: @shnk - yes, of course. Why would you feel any uncertainty about that? -- also, when in doubt, just test it. `try { using([...]) { throw new Exception("test"); } } catch (Exception e) { /* see if e.Message is "test". */ }`

Comment: @Corak then why do i see so many posts of people telling others to use a try/catch within a using block instead of outside. it makes absolutely no sense. try/catch should ALWAYS encapsulate the using block.

Comment: @shnk - Well, how about a situation like: `using (var thing = new WillAlwaysWork()) { /* some fancy but safe code */ try { /* some potentially dangerous code, but where failure can be handled locally */ } catch (LocallyHandleableException e) { /* handle e */ } /* more fancy code */ }`?

Comment: @shnk - You usually want to `try..catch` as close to where you can handle a specific exception as possible (but not closer). So if instantiating the `IDisposable` *could* throw an error which you *can* handle at that point, surround the `using` with `try..catch`. If you **can't** handle it there, then **don't**! Let it bubble up to where you **can**. And if something "inside" the using can go wrong, but you can also handle it inside, put the `try..catch` inside.

Comment: Alright i see your point. I guess what im trying to say is that a using statement wrapped by a try/catch will always be safe?

Comment: @shnk - You can be pretty sure that any catchable exception (counter example: OutOfMemoryException usually **can't** be caught) that happens inside a `try..catch`, either immediately inside, *or however deeply nested* (which includes any sub-scope as indicated by `{}` or function call or subfunction call etc.), will be caught by it, if you specify the specific exception (or superclass thereof) unless already caught inside (and not re-thrown).

Comment: @Corak Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Any exception thrown within the context of your try block will be handled by the corresponding catch block. You can have, in this instance, one try block that can catch exceptions from multiple sources and handle them as you wish. Consider the following code...

```
try
{
    using(var con = DataService.GetSomethingDisposable()) // Possible InvalidOperationException();
    {
        // Do what you need here
        // Possible Exception here
    }
}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    // Handle as you will
}
catch(Exception ex) // Catch any other exception
{
    // Handle as you will
}
```

So with this you can catch and respond to any exception that arises with the same try...catch block.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN Reference  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

> When the lifetime of an IDisposable object is limited to a single
>   method, you should declare and instantiate it in the using statement.
>   The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the
>   correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the
>   object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called. Within
>   the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or
>   reassigned.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 would catch both scenarios:

```
try { using() } catch (Exception) {}
```

If you create a new object which throws an exception on initialisation, the exception will be caught in your `catch` block.
Equally, if something inside your `using` block throws an exception, that will also be caught in the `catch` block.

An exception will always bubble up to the first `catch` block which is capturing that type of exception. If there's nothing to catch the exception, it'll likely bubble all the way up and terminate your application

Comment: So when would you use a try and catch within a using statement? It seems to me that try and catch should always encapsulate the using statement.

Comment: You can use a try catch block any time you want to handle an exception. If you wanted to do something else with the object created by the using after the exception, you'll need to put a try catch inside it. There's no reason you can't also encapsulate the entire using block in a different try catch though

Comment: What do you mean "do something else"? If "that something else" throws an exception wont the catch block outside of the using statement catch it anyways? I still dont see the point of putting a try and catch within a using statement.

Comment: By "do something else" I mean any other bit of code. For example, if you have a loop within the using block, you may want to continue the loop if any of them throw an exception, in this case you'd have a try catch block within the loop inside your using block. Exceptions only go to the _first_ catch block so it wouldn't bubble up to the outer catch unless you specifically re-throw the exception.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.